# FileUriExposedException android N and later

Tags: android, camera

I just managed to get the Camera working in my app on Android N , the problem is when i take the picture using the camera and click ok , it's return no photo to edit, ps :'my app is a photo editor" .
here's the changes i made in codes :

was:

```
private Uri getImageUri() {
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath(), fname);
    Uri tempURI = Uri.fromFile(file);
    Log.e("URI", ">> " + tempURI);
    return tempURI;
}
```

its become :

```
private Uri getImageUri() {
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath(), fname);
    Uri tempURI = GenericFileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", file);
    //Uri tempURI = Uri.fromFile(file);
    Log.e("URI", ">> " + tempURI);
    return tempURI;
}
```

and this :

```
case R.id.ic_camera:
    // root = this.getCacheDir();
    galleryopen = true;
    fname = "Style" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";

    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, getImageUri());
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, SELECT_CAMERA);
    break;
```

to :

```
case R.id.ic_camera:
    // root = this.getCacheDir();
    galleryopen = true;
    fname = "Style" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";

    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    cameraIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, getImageUri());
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, SELECT_CAMERA);
    break;
```

And i don't know what am i missing , i will appreciate your help , thank you

Answer (score 1):

Since about Android 5.1 and ultimately since Android 7 file uri are deprecated. Instead you have to use content uri via a fileprovider.

Read the FileProvider documentation to find out more about it: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html

and search for content uri or just the term FileUriExposedException and you'll find some good explanations in other stackoverflow threads.